# In SwifUI, how do I precisely center a view and place other views relative to it horizontally?

Tags: swiftui, layout, position, offset, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to place these Text views as follows

- "App title" in the center
- "Edit" and "..." (3-dot menu) on the far right

When I try the `.position()` modifier to manually center the "App title" precisely, that seems to work. However, its returned view takes up the entire available space and pushes the Text views for "Edit" and "..." completely out of the desired position.

```
struct SOPosition: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("App title")
                .border(Color.blue)
                .position(x: UIScreen.width / 2)
                .border(Color.red)
            Group {
                Text("Edit")
                Text("...")
            }.border(.yellow)
                .frame(alignment: .trailing)
        }
        
        Spacer()
    }
} // SOPosition
```

Below is a screenshot for it

[image: Layout using position() modifier]

When I try to use `.offset()` modifier, I get approximate result by tweaking the coordinate values. Is there a cleaner way which does not involve hard-coded values.

```
struct SOOffset: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("").frame(alignment: .leading)
            Spacer()
            Text("App title").offset(x: 40)
            Spacer()
            Group {
                Text("Edit")
                Text("...")
            }.frame(alignment: .trailing).offset(x: -20)
        }
        
        Spacer()
    }
} // SOOffset
```

Below is a screenshot for it

[image: Layout using offset() modifier]

Comment: SwiftUI.Layout allows for precise positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest showing the menu items in an overlay over the title, with trailing alignment. This way, if the title and the buttons have different heights, perhaps because the title uses a bigger font, they stay aligned in the vertical center.

When you want to have content fill the full width or height of the screen, you can either use a `Spacer` to hog the unused space (as you are doing), or you can use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)`. Both techniques are valid and sometimes you will want to use one, sometimes the other. However, two advantages of using `.frame` are:

- you can apply it to any element (there is no need to nest inside another stack)
- there are no issues of spacing between `Spacer` and other content (when used in a stack with non-zero spacing).

Also, if you need the exact size of the screen then you should use a `GeometryReader`. This works better for split screen on iPad. `UIScreen.main.bounds` is deprecated anyway.

So here is an updated version of your example:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("App title")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .border(Color.blue)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Edit")
                    Text("...")
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .border(.yellow)

        Text("main content")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I accepted this solution because it is bit simpler and thus easier to be understood to me. Also, it seems to handle the trailing alignment better.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the contents inside ZStack. Notice: when `App title` or `Edit ...` text is too long it will overlap each other.

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("App title")
            }

            Spacer()
        }

        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Text("Edit")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
            Text("...")
                .fixedSize()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct and the most Swifty solution. Using a ZStack makes the most sense in this scenario